# Adding table to existing LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query:

```
model.Queue = _db.Orders
                .Join(_db.Tool,
                    a => a.PART_KEY,
                    b => b.PART_KEY,
                    (a, b) => new { a, b })
                .Where(r => (r.a.PART_KEY == r.b.PART_KEY) && (r.b.Site == Site))
                .Where(r => (r.a.Start > 0) && (r.a.Finish == 0))
                .GroupBy(r => new { r.a.GROUP })
                .Select(r => new Queue
                {
                    name = r.Key.GROUP,
                    count = r.GroupBy(g => g.a.PART_KEY).Count(),
                    average = r.Average(g => g.a.DaysInSequence)
                });
```

The query is currently used to generate metrics for the users. The users now want metrics expanded to encompass completed orders from the table `OrdersCompleted`. In the database, when an order is completed, the entire order is moved from `Orders` to `OrdersComplete`. Both tables have the same structure, that is, same columns and identical model classes.

It looks like the extension method I need to use is `Concat`, but I am having issues figuring out the syntax to make it work with this particular query. It seems like adding `.Concat(_db.OrdersComplete)` as the first extension method should work, but that seems to not be the case.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, but it really sounds like you DB needs to be redone.  Two tables with the same columns is almost always a design flaw.  Why not have a Completed flag column?

Comment: @juharr It can make sense in some situations.  If you rarely need to access the historical data it can be a performance optimization to segregate out the recent orders.  It's also possible that orders shouldn't be editable once they're completed, and having different tables would allow different permission levels (edit in the non-completed, but only create and no edit/delete in the completed table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even if the two tables have exactly the same columns with exactly the same types and names, the tool that generates the classes will create two types with different names.  Since the types aren't *exactly* the same, `Concat` won't work.  You need to do something to map one or both tables so that they share a type.

One option is to map both of them to an anonymous type.  Add something like:

```
.Select(o => new
{
    o.PART_KEY,
    o.GROUP
    //Any other columns you need from each order
});
```

after both `_db.Orders` as well as `_db.OrdersComplete`.  Then the `Concat` will work.

Another option, if you think that it'll be common for you to need to handle all of the combined orders would be to address the underlying issue of the DB classes not being related.  You could modify the actual DB objects to make this easier in all queries.

One option would be to create either an interface, or a base type, that both of the classes can extend/implement.  If you create an interface with all of the columns the two types share and have both of them implement the interface then you can use `Concat` to create an enumeration of that interface.  (Not sure how well that will play with Linq-To-Sql though.)

A third option would be to create a View in the database that, under the hood, was just a `Union All` on these two tables, possibly pulling a subset of the columns from one or both tables.  You could then query off of that view, instead of concating the tables yourself.

Comment: I had a idea that this may have been the issue. What if I needed all the columns? Would I need to type them all out or is there an equivalent of `SELECT *` for LINQ? I also thought about having the underlying DB tables changed as I really don't like this structure either, but many of our applications use these tables already and only the DBA can make these changes.

Comment: @Jeff You would need to type out all of the columns used in that query.  There is no way to pull all columns.  You wouldn't need to change the actual DB for the second option, just the C# objects that represent those columns.

Comment: I guess I'm not completely understanding what you mean in option 2. Perhaps you could edit your answer to include a very small example of this "interface". I am pretty new to object oriented programming and c# in general, so perhaps that is the issue. P.S. Option 1 worked for me, but I would still like to learn more about option 2

Comment: @Jeff Create an interface.  Give it a property for each column shared by both tables, and of the appropriate type.  Then just go to the definition of the class for each of those tables and add make them implement that interface.  Once you've done that you can cast both sequences to `IEnumerable<IOrder>` (or whatever you called it`) and use `Concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Servy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14201711/285002) is correct: the easiest way to do this is to essentially create an anonymous class from each of the two queries.  As long as the anonymous classes have the same properties, both `Concat` and `Union` will work.

One possible alternative is to run the same query on both tables (since you are already projecting the results into a new `Queue` object, and `Concat` the results from the two queries.

Comment: Nope, `Union` will have the same problem as `Concat`.  The generics force the two sequences to have the same type.

Comment: The tables, aside from the data within, are identical in structure.

Comment: @Jeff Which doesn't matter.  They're still different types, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Note that if you `Concat` the results, and not the tables at the start, it results in shorter, clearer, simpler code, but it will take almost 2x longer to execute as you're performing two database queries.